# How to find/detect optimal parameters of a Grid Search in Libsvm+Weka?

Tags: weka, svm, libsvm, optional-parameters

I'm trying to use SVM with Weka framework. So i'm using Libsvm. I'm new to SVM and reading the guide on the site of Libsvm I read that is possible to discover optimal parameters for SVM (cost and gamma) using GridSearch. So i choose Grid Search on Weka and I obtained a bad classification results (TN rate around 1%). So how do I have to interpret these results? If using optimal parameter I got bad results is there no chance for me to get better classification?What I mean is: Grid Search give me the Best results that i can obtain using SVM?

My dataset is formed by 1124 instances (89% negative class, 11% positive class) and there are 31 attributes (2 of them are nominal others are numeric). I'm using a cross validation (10-fold) on the whole dataset to test the model.
I tried to use GridSearch (I normalized each attribute values between 0 and 1, no features selection but I change class value from 0 and 1 to 1 and -1 accroding to SVM theory but T don't know if it useful) with these parameters: cost from 1 to 18 with 1.0 step and gamma from -5 to 10 with 1.0 step. Results are sensitivity 93,6% and specificity 64.8% but these takes around 1 hour to complete computation!!

I'd like to get better results compared with decision tree. Using Features Selection (Info Gain ranking) + SMOTE oversampling + Cost Sensitive Learning I obtained sensitivity 91% and specificity 80%. Is there a way to tune SVM without trying every possible range of values for cost and gamma?

Comment: In my experience SVM is able to do at least as well as other classification algorithms with optimal parameters.  It's drawback is the computational complexity. Please edit your question to include more info.  What is the range of C and gamma you did the grid search over and in what increments?  What data are you using to test the model on?  How many features do you have and what type? How many data instances?  What is the ratio between the number of pos & neg examples in your training set? Did you do any preprocessing? (e.g. scaling, feature selection, transform from categorical to numeric)

Comment: Ah, okay, so I think your problem lies in the way you are searching for parameters.  Every data set is different, but when I search for C, I generally go in orders of magnitude and start much smaller, so from 0.00001 to 10, but trying 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, etc.  Same idea with Gamma, try very small values and vary them in orders of magnitude, not equal amounts.

Comment: For the nominal features, you should be converting them to 1 binary feature each nominal value.  So if you have a feature color: red, blue or green, it should become color_red: 1 or 0, color_blue: 1 or 0, color_green: 1 or 0 (technically you can have n-1 for n values, since one can be represented by 0 in the others).  You cannot simply convert color to be red=1, blue=2, green=3, since this implies red and green are further apart than blue and red. Since SVM is based on data instances being points in hyperdimensional space, this can throw your results.

Comment: Ok I'll try with small values, but I'm realizing that it required a lot of time for computation!! About nominal values I've got "Sex" (1,2) is it necessary to convert it to (0,1)? And another nominal attribute has 6 possible values, so is it necessary to create other 6 new attributes each one binary for a certain value? And last thing...is it necessary to convert values of class attribute from (0,1) to (-1,1) as in SVM theory?

Comment: Yes on the first two.  For the third, class attribute does need to be -1 and 1 for SVM, but I'm not sure if somewhere in the weka libsvm interface it takes care of that conversion.  However if you are having problems I would recommend doing that.  Assigning -1 and 1 to the classes is fundamental to the mathematics, so it has to be done somewhere to get good results.

Comment: I believe you can use one of WEka's filters to do those conversions for you btw

Comment: Part of the reason your computation is taking so long is the 10 fold cross-validation.  To get an idea of what a reasonable range to search would be, try doing it without cross-validation, then use cross validation on the most likely range of values.  Also, When you set C to be very large, you are essentially telling the SVM you want  a precise solution - you don't want to allow too many training points to be misscategorized or "stray" into the margin.  This takes longer to converge on a solution and results in overfitting.  When you run with a smaller value, you should find its faster.

Comment: Well I did everything you suggested (nominal to binary and +1;-1 class). I tried several couple of low value for cost and gamma (with RBF as kernel): (1e-6,0),(1e-6,1),(1e-6,1e-6),(1e-5,1e-6),(1e-4,1e-5),(1e-3,1e-3),(1e-3,1),(1e-3,10) and all of them give me as results: 100% specificity and 0% sensitivity! How is this possible? Is there something wrong? Is there something else to tune? I saw a small improvement with cost=1 and gamma=10 where I obtained 100% specificity and 1,6% sensitivity

Comment: You really need to do a grid search.  By just poking around randomly you are hitting only about 7% of the search space.  Also, don't use 0 for either gamma or C.  Both are used through multiplication and using 0 for gamma is completely useless as every kernel evaluation will be 0.  C=0 gives you hard margin SVM so your data has to fit perfectly.  Also, I apologize, you should try larger values of C than 10, but gamma works best with smaller values.  I would start with a grid search from -5 to 10 for lg(C) and -15 to 2 for lg(gamma) doing maybe 10 steps for each.

Comment: I tried with several values as you suggest, I link the table I obtained. Each couple represent (sensitivity/specificity). As you can notice I obtain very low value for sensitivity.  Are this values normal? [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=n8804&s=6) I have no idea how to improve them!

Comment: Can you post more information? Sensitivity and Specificity aren't the whole picture. For a single run, using the best parameters you are getting there, the cell which got 52/97.5, just run it once (no need for CV) and let me know how many training points do you have? How many +1? How many -1? How many test points? When you run with those params, how many True positive, false positive, true negative, false negative?

Comment: What do you mean with "single run"? Do I have to validate with the complete dataset (1124 record)?

Comment: Yes, I just meant don't do the whole grid search again or anything, I just want to understand the breakdown.

Comment: Here you have the output of Weka [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=24157he&s=6)

Comment: Ah, now I see. I generally do a grid search looking for the highest accuracy, and you have a 93% accuracy, that is pretty good.  What your sensitivity and specificity are telling you is that your model is much better at being right about a test case that should be negative than a positive.  This is really not all that surprising given you have significantly more negative examples.  When you say you getting worse results than decision tree are you comparing only sensitivity and specificity?

Comment: Here is an example where this might throw you. Imagine in this case if instead of classifying things as they were, instead your model classified pos 116 correct and 7 wrong, and neg 100 correct and 1001 wrong.  Your sensitivity would be 0.94 and your specificity would be 0.9.  Would you consider that better than 0.53 and 0.98?  However, the accuracy would only be 0.90 instead of 0.93.  It would have classified an additional 30 instances incorrectly over the other model.  The mistakes would be more equally proportionate between the two classes, but there would be more.

Comment: So, generally in a grid search we optimize for accuracy. (FP+FN)/(FP+FN+TP+TN)  However, if in your situation say false positives are unacceptable, and you would rather have more mistakes overall than allow any false positives, then  optimize for sensitivity.  You could do a grid search and choose the parameters which give you 1.0 sensitivity and then the highest accuracy or specificity.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've got imbalance problem. It's a medical dataset so False negative are really bad. Yes, I'm comparing decision tree with SVM only about specificity and sensitivity. Do you think I can obtain desired results only using SVM? Or have I to merge it with other techniques as oversampling, feature selection or   Cost Sensitive Learning?

Comment: Using Weka and grid search doesn't seem to be possible optimize about specificity. How could I do it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about that, I've never actually used the grid search feature in Weka, I just use weka's test features to set up a series of tests and collected all the results

Comment: Can you suggest me how could I run a Grid Search optimizing for specificity rather than accuracy using other tools? What tool do you usually use?

Comment: I've used weka, I just didn't use a grid search feature in weka, I just set it up to run a series of tests with those parameters, then put the results in a spreadsheet and looked what had the best.  However, a shell script calling libsvm directly and then parsing the output would work well.